# How to make reports work?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a problem developing a desktop application with `C#` language and `IDE VISUAL STUDIO 2010`. The application is layered (data layer, business layer, presentation layer), I use crystal report to make reports when I installer the application install it on the client punctured all well the only thing not working is the reports I have this error:

> could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version = 4.0.0.0,
>   Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.el system can not find the specified file

Comment: Is the system.web dll added as a reference or deployed to the bin directory? It should be

Comment: You need to include the System.Web assembly in your installer, the client likely has the .NET 4.0 Client version instead of the full .NET 4.0.